# Need help optimizing basic join operation, on a table with 100K+ rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to create a page of status/message updates for a particular entity. A user can 
subscribe to any number of entities, and on this page you'd get the most recent information. 
My current query takes a while to run ( 1.3+ seconds, in a test table with 200K rows ), 
which just grabs 50 or so rows

The schema is:

entity:

```
  entity_id, message, timestamp
```

user

```
  user_id
```

subscription

```
  user_id, entity_id
```

The query is:

```
   SELECT entity.*
   FROM entity
   INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = entity.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY entity.timetamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

The problem from the database side seems to be this:

```
   Copying to tmp table 0.033285
   converting HEAP to MyISAM    0.031850
   Copying to tmp table on disk 1.177973
   Sorting result   0.064075
```

on the subscription table, I get the following explain infomration: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

I am using InnoDB tables, and I have indexes on the entity_id, user_id, and timestamp columns

Update:  It appears that the order by might be contributing or is the problem.  I have an index on the timestamp column, so apart from that, what else can I do to get the most recent messages more quickly?

Update: When I remove the order by clause, the query runs quickly.  .0006 seconds vs 1.3.  So I tried getting the data first via a sub query then running order by, but this doesn't do anything.

The query used was:

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM ( 
   SELECT entity.*
   FROM entity
   INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = entity.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
) as tbl
ORDER BY tbl.timetamp DESC
```

Comment: Is selecting all columns from entity really important?

Comment: It is not, however, changing it to just entity.message made no difference.

Comment: Do you have indexes on all those columns mentioned across all tables?  Can show add SHOW CREATE TABLE results for all tables in your question? Can you provide information on how much memory you have allocated (key_buffer_size, sort_buffer_size, etc.)?

Comment: What is the datatype of messages column? If it is a small column you could try creating a covering index on (entityid, timestamp, messages)

Comment: id columns are BIGINT, message is VARCHAR(255). I have not yet touched key_buffer_size, or sort_buffer_size, they are 8388608, and 2097152 respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT entity.* FROM
entity
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT *
  FROM subscription 
  WHERE user_id = 1
 ) AS subscriptions_for_user ON subscriptions_for_user.entity_id = entity.entity_id
ORDER BY entity.timetamp DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

in this way you just join with the subscriptions corresponding to user_id which is less quantity of data.

Comment: I actually do have an index on the timestamp column, just edited my post to add that

Comment: If using a modern version of MySQL, I would disagree with comment about using MyISAM over InnoDB.  InnoDB continues to be improved upon (whereh MyISAM is not being actively improved) to the point where InnoDB out-performs MyISAM for most types of workloads in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity table, you want a *single* index that covers *both* entity_id and timestamp, *in that order*. Best if this is the primary key. On the subscription table, you want an index that covers *both* user_id and entity_id, *in that order*. It's important that these indexes include both columns in the same index.

Once that is done, you want to make sure you let MySql have enough RAM that it is able to keep both tables *and the indexes* in RAM, in their entirety, and then run a few sample queries to "warm up" the database cache before doing your actual benchmarks.

I'd also suggest that you want a  message table that is separate from the entity table, and it's really the message table you will be looking at here.

Comment: I've set up the composite indexes but it hasn't made a difference, the issue seems to be the order by clause but I can't figure out how to correct it.  I've tried using a subquery to get all the data first, then sorting, but it does not offer any improvement

Comment: Try adding timestamp DESC to the first index

Comment: Hi Joel,  I've added the index to no avail.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure that you didn’t mean TOP 50 for Each EntityID, in this case the query will be very different.
The way you have used LIMIT in query it means at most you will get 50 rows ordered by Timestamp.

If the second is true, then you can filter the large table very first time only.
Also if you use “Order By” in your query try to come up with constants/list that can used in WHERE condition.
That way DB engine can utilize Indexes more efficiently.

**Indexes you need.**

Table Entity:

```
TimeStamp DESC, EntityID ASC, Message ASC
```

Table subscription:

```
User_id,entity_ID
```

Try this Query

```
    SET @Rownum=1
    SET @PValue=''

    SELECT Entity_ID,Message,TIMESTAMP
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @Rownum:=IF(@Timestamp=Timestamp, @Rownum+1,1) AS RowNumber
            ,Entity_ID
            ,MESSAGE
            ,TimeStamp
            @Timestamp=@Timestamp AS DummyTimeStamp
        FROM Enitty
        WHERE Entity_ID IN (SELECT Entity_ID FROM Subscription WHERE USER_ID = 1)
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
    )qry
    WHERE RowNumber <=50
```